Remove toolbar item in Safari App Extension
I have a safari app extension that has a toolbar item which shows a popover when clicked. However, I want to remove the entire toolbar item for my extension. Is that possible? If so, how do I do it?
I have tried removing SFSafariToolbarItem from Info.plist, removing toolbar related function like
override func validateToolbarItem(in window: SFSafariWindow, validationHandler:@escaping ((Bool, String) -> Void))

override func popoverViewController() -> SFSafariExtensionViewController

But the toolbar item is still displayed, even if it is not functional.
